# PIG Join includes Bag that must be filtered with value outside the Bag

Tags: hadoop, tuples, apache-pig, filtering, bag

I'm coming up to speed on PIG and am combining web_log data and stock pricing history from two sources. The date/time is normalized to a timestamp and a join is performed on the stock symbol. Timestamps do not match.

```
jnd = JOIN web_time BY w_sym, stock_sort BY group;
```

The group contains a Bag of stock data specific to the symbol. Here's the combined schema.

**jnd: {web_time::ip: chararray,web_time::user: chararray,web_time::w_time: long,web_time::url: chararray,stock_sort::sort: {(sym: chararray,time: long,price: double)}}**

I need to filter the stock_sort Bag using web_time::w_time and time, it is not an exact match. Sample JND data looks like this.

(14.192.253.226,voraciouszing,*1213201721000*,"GET /VLCCF.html HTTP/1.0",{(VLCCF,*1265361975000*,13.84),(VLCCF,*1265262560000*,14.16),(VLCCF,*1265192740000*,14.44),(VLCCF,*1265099390000*,14.48),(VLCCF,*1265028034000*,14.5),(VLCCF,*1262678148000*,13.76),(VLCCF,*1262607761000*,13.82),(VLCCF,*1233832497000*,16.9),(VLCCF,*1233740569000*,16.96) ... ,(VLCCF,*884004754000*,23.99),(VLCCF,*883720431000*,23.57)})

Using the value in $2, ultimately I need to filter all but one entry but for now I'm attempting to remove tuples with a smaller timestamp.

```
flake = FOREACH jnd {
    fits = FILTER jnd BY (w_time > time);
    GENERATE ip, user, w_time, url, fits;
    }
```

The above doesn't work, it is step 1 to remove all Bag tuples with timestamps smaller than the desired time (w_time). w_time isn't part of group. Does this really require a UDF or am I missing something simple? I'm at a standstill.

### Development Environment

Apache Pig version 0.15.0.2.4.0.0-169 (rexported) 
compiled Feb 10 2016, 07:50:04
Hadoop 2.7.1.2.4.0.0-169
Subversion git@github.com:hortonworks/hadoop.git -r 26104d8ac833884c8776473823007f17
4-node Hortonworks Cluster

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: 2016-04-27 09:45:17,355 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias flake. Backend error : org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (141.60.212.117,boredadoring,1171290133000,"GET /CME.html HTTP/1.0",CME,CME,{(CME,1265360529000,282.67),(CME,1265301922000,286.5)................ (CME,1041573707000,45.8),(CME,1041507691000,43.95)}) (common cause: "JOIN" then "FOREACH ... GENERATE foo.bar" should be "foo::bar" )

Answer (score 0):

I think in your foreach, you need to filter stock_sort::sort. Not JND. And the filtering should be done by jnd.w_time > time. I managed to write the entire flow; no UDFs. See below.

took two files:

xact.txt:

```
VLCCF,1265361975000,13.84
VLCCF,1265262560000,14.16
VLCCF,1265192740000,14.44
VLCCF,1265099390000,14.48
VLCCF,1265028034000,14.5
VLCCF,1262678148000,13.76
VLCCF,1262607761000,13.82
VLCCF,1233832497000,16.9
VLCCF,1233740569000,16.96
VLCCF,884004754000,23.99
VLCCF,883720431000,23.5
```

stock.txt

14.192.253.226,voraciouszing,1213201721000,"GET /VLCCF.html HTTP/1.0",VLCCF

```
stock = load 'stock.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (
ip:chararray,
user:chararray,
w_time:long,
url:chararray,
symbol:chararray
);

xact = load 'xact.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (
symbol:chararray,
time:long,
price:double
);

xact_grouped = foreach(group xact by symbol) generate
    group, xact;

joined = join stock by symbol, xact_grouped by group;

filtered = foreach joined {
    grp = filter xact by time < joined.w_time;
    generate ip, grp;
};

dump filtered;
```

Gave me

(14.192.253.226,{(VLCCF,884004754000,23.99),(VLCCF,883720431000,23.5)})

EDITED: Alternatively

```
stock = load 'stock.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (
ip:chararray,
user:chararray,
w_time:long,
url:chararray,
symbol:chararray
);

xact = load 'xact.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (
symbol:chararray,
time:long,
price:double
);

joined = join stock by symbol, xact by symbol;

joined_filtered = foreach (filter joined by time < w_time) generate
    ip as ip,
    user as user,
    w_time as w_time,
    stock::symbol as symbol,
    time as time,
    price as price;

grouped = foreach (group joined_filtered by (ip, user, w_time)) generate
    flatten(group),
    joined_filtered;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I get an error - ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. See the initial post comment. My stock.txt file contains thousands of lines so each log groups to a stock_sort::sort containing an xact Bag.

Comment: can you try joining, filtering and only then grouping? (see my edited answer)

Comment: Working on it now. Thanks again for the input. I'll post an update.

Comment: After spending several days fighting Jython, I ended up writing a python UDF for this job which runs on a cluster. The problem is an internal bags within an outer bag can't be parsed via FOREACH with Pig. I'm not sure why this isn't supported but it sucks. My UDF returns a single tuple from the internal bag and this approach works with an outer bag FOREACH. Thanks for the help.